# How do I make the Python program to execute itself again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a program that keep running asking for new inputs. I want to create a file such that it opens the command prompt asking the user to input some values. The user inserts the inputs, the program returns a answer and it restarts so the user will be able to insert new inputs to get new answers. It will be done until the user closes the command window.

I created a code that give to me the weekday of any date in Gregorian Calendar. I used John Conway's "Doomsday Algorithm" to write the program. It works fine when I run it. I created a input section where the program asks for the Day, Month and Year. Look my following code:

```py
#The first part of my doomsday algorithm here (this is to large to simple paste here).
#The last part is creating the last function, that will evaluate everything

def semana(d,m,a):

#definition of the function "semana". 
#I'm Brazilian and this is the portuguese word for "week". 
#Then I insert the input strings here:

x=eval(input("Dia:"))
y=eval(input("Mês:"))
z=eval(input("Ano:"))

semana(x,y,z)
```

I run the program on command prompt and I enter the values for the variables `x`,`y` and `z`, I press enter and the program shows the correct answer, but it terminates itself right after the answer appears.

I want to know how to make the program to restart in the same window. What I mean is: I insert the values for `x`,`y` and `z`. Then I press enter and the program shows the answer. Then it asks again for the input so I will be able to keep inserting values and receiving the weekday as answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `while True:`.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is a [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) loop. This control structures allows us to execute a set of statements as long as a condition is `True`. If the condition becomes `False`, we break out of the loop.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

def semana():
    x=input("Dia:")
    y=input("Mes:")
    z=input("Ano:")
    print('{}/{}/{}'.format(x,y,z))

while True:
    semana()
```

Example output

```
Dia:6
Mes:14
Ano:2019
6/14/2019
```