# Trying to loop back to the start of the program when the user answers "Yes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I would like my program to loop back up to the original question if a user would like to place a second order.   Unfortunately, I cannot figure it out and am beyond frustrated.

```py
import pprint

sizes = {'1':"tiny",'2':"small",'3':"normal",'4':"American"}

print('Welcome to The Tropical Shaved Ice Emporium\n')

print('Here are the sizes available')
print('Code','Size')
for code,size in sizes.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(code, size))
result = input('\n\nPlease choose a size by typing the numeric code: ')
if int(result) == 1 or int(result) == 2 or int(result) == 3 or int(result) == 4:
    print('\nThank you for your order.')
else:
    print('There is not a size with that code\nPlease try again')
        ###woulld like this to go up to line 7 or 11 so they can try again###
result2 = input('\nWould you like to order another item?\nY or N?   ')
if result2 == 'Y':
        ###woulld like this to go up to line 7 or 11 so they can try again###
    if result2 == 'N':
        print('Thank you for your order')
```

the program just ends!   I have absolutely no idea how to take it back up to the original question, 'Please choose a size by typing the numeric code: '

Comment: What sorts of loops do you know about? What tutorial etc. have you been using to learn Python from? It might be easier if we can just give you a page reference in there.

Comment: Look into [while loops](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_loops.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the Python program to execute itself again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606939/how-do-i-make-the-python-program-to-execute-itself-again)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a `while` loop.

```
# keep looping forever, until the user wants to stop
while True:

    # ask for size etc.

    # now ask if they want another order
    answer = input('Would you like to place another order? (y/n) ')
    if answer == 'n':
        # end the loop
        print('Thank you.')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the question for what size to get in a function, and call that function when the user enters yes.
I also improved your code to not be case sensitive and ask again if the y/n answer is invalid

```py
import pprint

sizes = {'1':"tiny",'2':"small",'3':"normal",'4':"American"}

print('Welcome to The Tropical Shaved Ice Emporium\n')

def ask():
    print('Here are the sizes available')
    print('Code','Size')
    for code,size in sizes.items():
        print('{} {}'.format(code, size))
    result = input('\n\nPlease choose a size by typing the numeric code: ')
    if int(result) == 1 or int(result) == 2 or int(result) == 3 or int(result) == 4:
        print('\nThank you for your order.')
    else:
        print('There is not a size with that code\nPlease try again')
        ###woulld like this to go up to line 7 or 11 so they can try again###
    ask_to_continue()
def ask_to_continue():
    result2 = input('\nWould you like to order another item?\nY or N?   ')
    if result2.upper() == 'Y':
        ask()
    elif result2.upper() == 'N':
        print('Thank you for your order')
    else:
        ask_to_continue()
ask()
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for such FAST responses!   I am taking an online extension class at the University of California San Diego (UCSD) and have done some programming in VBA and SQL.   This is my first go-round with Python.   I have been so frustrated that with the information given to us, I could not make this part of the programming a sub-function that I could call.   Seeing this 'def' function is really what I needed and glad it does exist.   Need to get beyond just materials shared within the course!  Thanks again -  Lauren